# How to change the background color of tree-view in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

I need help in changing the background color of the treeview on kivy.

I am working on the kivy framework in python that will list some labels.

But what happens while executing the application is, my apps background color is white and the tree-view gets the background-color from the application background.

Below is the sample-screenshot

[image]

**Sample Code:**  To create tree view.

```
list_label=TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My root label'),hide_root=False)
list_label.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My first item'))
```

Comment: You really should include the code (.kv or .py) you're using currently to create/draw your treeview.

Comment: @MikahBarnett Thanks for the reply. Kindly review my updated question. I have only used .py file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `.py`:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<TreeView>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

''')
```

This changes the background to red. You can replace `1, 0, 0, 1` with any color you prefer.

You can do this entirely in `Python`, but you will need to manually create bindings that `kv` creates for you automatically:

```
    list_label=TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My root label'),hide_root=False)

    with list_label.canvas.before:
        Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
        self.background_rect = Rectangle()
    list_label.bind(pos=self.adjust_rect_pos)
    list_label.bind(size=self.adjust_rect_size)

def adjust_rect_size(self, treeview, new_size):
    self.background_rect.size = new_size

def adjust_rect_pos(self, treeview, new_pos):
    self.background_rect.pos = new_pos
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,Can you please explain me how to use canvas.before without **Builder.load_string**

Comment: Thanks for reply it is working fine. And can you explain me how to delete all nodes in a treeview

Comment: In this forum you are only supposed to ask one question per posting. To get an answer to that question, please post it as a new question along with what you have attempted already.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have posted new question. check this below URL .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534713/how-to-delete-all-nodes-on-a-tree-view-in-kivy-framework

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I kind of answered the wrong question, my solution below changes the color of the even/odd nodes which overlay the background.  I'll leave it here in case it's helpful.

**Original Answer:**

There are a couple ways to skin this cat.  The easiest is to use the `even_color` and `odd_color` properties of the `TreeViewNode` widget.  Here's how you would use that in your case:

```
list_label=TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My root label'),hide_root=False)
list_label.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='My first item', \
even_color=[0.5,0.1,0.1,1],odd_color=[0.1,0.1,0.5,1]))
```

It would definitely be more *DRY* to create your own custom widget which is equally easy:

```
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyTreeViewLabel(Button, TreeViewLabel):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(MyTreeViewLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.even_color = [0.5,0.1,0.1,1]
      self.odd_color = [0.1,0.1,0.5,1]
```

Then, your code would just be:

```
list_label=TreeView(root_options=dict(text='My root label'),hide_root=False)
list_label.add_node(MyTreeViewLabel(text='My first item'))
```