# How to delete all nodes on a tree-view in kivy framework

Tags: python, kivy

I need help in deleting all nodes in a treeview.

I am working on the kivy framework in python that will list some labels.

But what happens while removing node is some of the node are deleted and other nodes still present in the treeview.

**Sample code:**

```
for node in treeview.iterate_open_nodes():
   treeview.remove_node(node)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in removing items from an iterable while iterating.
You should first collect the items and then remove them

```py
    for node in [i for i in treeview.iterate_all_nodes()]:
       treeview.remove_node(node)
```

Comment: Nince answer ! A go-to pitfall for first timers !

Answer (score 0):

You should use `iterate_all_nodes` instead of `iterate_open_nodes` as it iterates only over all the expended nodes

Comment: @abhib Thanks for reply. I have also used **iterate_all_nodes** but it is not working. A few nodes were deleted

Answer (score 0):

I am using convert to list:

```
for i in list(treeview.iterate_all_nodes()):
    treeview.remove_node(i)
```